# How can I create a subclass that inherit Ellipse class

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, windows-phone-8

I'm new to C# language, and I am having some trouble with creating a subclass that inherits properties of some class. I'm using Visual Studio 2012 to create Windows Phone 8 apps.

I have no trouble in inheriting classes like Button or TextBox, but I can't make it inherit Ellipse class. I can inherit Shape class, from which Ellipse is derived, but can't inherit Ellipse itself.

The idea is to add some properties to the Ellipses that I create, so I can keep track of in which order the user is pressing these ellipses. I could use another class, or use Ellipse itself (and play with its already existing properties), but for learning purposes I'd like to know why I can't (or how I can) inherit Ellipse class.

```
public partial class Ball : Ellipse
{
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Ellipse` is `sealed` and `sealed` means "cannot be inherited" you cannot inherit it.

Alternatevily you can use [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) which helps us to extend behaviors of classes without inheritance.

```
public abstract class ShapeDecorator : Shape {
     protected Shape Shape {get; private set;}

     protected(Shape shape) {
          this.Shape = shape;
     }
}

public abstract class EllipseDecorator : ShapeDecorator {
      protected(Ellipse ellipse) : base(shape) {
      }

      public Ellipse Ellipse { get { (Ellipse)base.Shape; } }

      // Here, if you wish, you can override some methods using Ellipse features inside
      // So that your Shape acts as Ellipse
}

public class Ball : EllipseDecorator {
    public Ball() : base(new Ellipse()) {
         // you can initialize base.Ellipse here
    }

    // Now you can add your Ball specific methods here
    // You can still override some methods here
    // So that your ellipse acts as Ball
}
```

Now, if any method requires a parameter of type `Ellipse` you can pass `ball.Ellipse`. If it accepts a parameter of type `Shape` you can pass your `Ball` object directly.

Answer (score 7):

You can't.  [`Ellipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `sealed`.

You could *wrap* it, but you can't *inherit* from it.

```
public class MyEllipse: Shape
{
   private Ellipse _Ellipse;

   // pass through overridden Shape methods/properties to the underlying Ellipse

   // add custom methods/properties.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[`Ellipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is defined as `sealed`:

```
public sealed class Ellipse : Shape
```

[`sealed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) means

> When applied to a class, the sealed modifier prevents other classes from inheriting from it.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the class is [sealed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) as can be seen [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.shapes.ellipse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It means that subclassing isn't in fact allowed. As other answers state, it may still be wrapped.